# Write list to file using Pickle

Tags: python, file-io

I am reading a set of files to a list and writing the list to a single file using `Pickle.dump`. But some invalid characters are added in the new file at the beginning like `\80]q\00(XK\00\00\00`. How can I remove these?

```
if(gyro):
            lines = []
            for fil in gyro:
                file_name = os.path.join(file_path,fil)
                file_data = open(file_name)
                lines.extend(file_data.readlines())
                file_data.close
                os.remove(file_name)     
            uncompressed_filename = "raw_gyro.txt"
            uncompressed_filename = os.path.join(file_path,uncompressed_filename)
            with open(uncompressed_filename, "wb") as fp3:
                print("Created",uncompressed_filename)
                pickle.dump(lines, fp3)
```

Comment: aren't they part of the pickel serialization deserialization thing?
How are you opening those files? Are you aware you need to do sth like pickle.load(file) to open them?

Comment: These are just for reading manually. Is the dump used only if the files are to be read by pickle again? However, I used the writelines to write to file, it works.